# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type?

Tags: c#

i have got this error

```
Error   3   Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
```

my problem here

```
if (client["banhours"] == 0)
{
    client["banhours"] = -1;
    client["banreason"] = "Infinite time.";
    client["banstamp"] = DateTime.Now.AddYears(100);
}
if (Account.State == Database.AccountTable.AccountState.Banned)
{
    if (client["banhours"] != -1)
    {
        DateTime banStamp = client["banstamp"];
        if (DateTime.Now > banStamp.AddDays(((int)client["banhours"]) / 24).AddHours(((int)client["banhours"]) % 24))
            Account.State = Database.AccountTable.AccountState.Player;
    }
}
```

client is >>>
 Client.GameClient client;

Comment: What is client? can we have more code ?

Comment: Please post the code for GameClient

Comment: What is `GameClient`? Where does it come from? Why do you think you can use indexing with it?

Comment: gameclient is class and he is big in variables and void !

Comment: This question is unanswerable.. We would need the code for `GameClient`.

Comment: here for download http://www.mediafire.com/download/77ex3gtve636s1o/GameState.cs             and here for viwe                http://www.mediafire.com/view/77ex3gtve636s1o/GameState.cs

Comment: Really, you want someone to read through a 273kb C# file?  Please narrow down your question so that other can help you easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried client.banhours or client.banreason?

If Client.GameClient is a class and those are properties or fields, they must not be accessed like an array or dictionary.

Comment: yes and i faild :( but in old project work fine , without error